# A query by using count with multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL.

I have a movie database. With the following tables with the following with their columns listed:

**Category Table**

columns - `category_id`, `name`, `last_update`

**Film_Category Table**

columns - `film id`, `category id`, `last_update`

**Inventory Table**

columns - `inventory_id`, `film_id`, `store_id`, `last_update`

**Rental Table**

columns - `rental_id`, `rental_date`, `inventory_id`, `customer_id`, `return_date`, `staff_id`, `last_update`

**Film Table**

columns - `film_id`, `title`

**Question/ Issue**
I wish to create a query that lists each movie, the film category it is classified in, and how often it is rented. I wish to use the data from the five tables as much as possible.

I want the table to output the film title column, the category name column and the count of how many times it is rented out. The output should be something like this:

```
title              name          rental_count
Alter Victory      Animation         10
Goofy Movie        Animation         20
```

Help would really be appreciated for this task!

Comment: add  a proper data sample  .. the expected  result and the query you tried to write

Comment: @scaisEdge I added how I want the output.

Comment: without a proper data sample that explain how the tables Rental and Inventory are really relateted .. is not clar to me how answer  to your question  ... so  add  a clear data sample too

Comment: You missed quite a few parts of what scaisEdge's request. Also , pls see the following links on how to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I removed the conflicting product tags as well. Pls add the one back that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use join and aggregate function `count`

```
select F.title,C.name,count(rental_id) as rental_count from Rental R
    left join Inventory I on R.inventory_id=I.inventory_id
    inner join Film_Category Fc  on I.film_id=Fc.film_id
    inner join Flim F on F.film_id=Fc.film_id
    inner join Category C on Fc.category_id=C.category_id
group by F.title,C.name
```

Comment: I tried this. However, I get a syntax error                                                       `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="`
`LINE :     inner join Flim F on F.film_id=Fc=film_id`

Comment: @DeepakM yap extra = was there now edited you can check it now or if have fiddle link you can provide me so that i can check as well

Comment: @DeepakM any reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177404/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-deepak-m).

Comment: Just one thing @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin. Can you just edit to make the count column the last column in the query instead of the first! thanks!

Comment: @ Zaynul Abadin Tuhin Please check chatroom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 WITH film_rents AS 
(
SELECT  I.film_id, COUNT(1) AS rental_count
FROM Inventory AS I
INNER JOIN Rental AS R ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
GROUP BY I.film_id)

SELECT F.title, ISNULL(rental_count, 0 ) AS rental_count, C.name     
FROM  Film AS F 
LEFT  JOIN  film_rents AS FR ON F.film_id = FR.film_id
INNER JOIN Film_Category AS FC ON FC.film_id = F.film_id
INNER JOIN Category AS C ON C.category_id = FC.category_id
```

this does what you asked, however I think what you really wants is more than this. I am saying this because you have a junction table Film_Category which means for one film there is one or more categories. in that case the query you asked for ( and above query) does not do the job for you. Asuming you are using SQL‌ Server 2017 you can use this:

```
WITH film_rents AS 
(
SELECT  I.film_id, COUNT(1) AS rental_count
FROM Inventory AS I
INNER JOIN Rental AS R ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
GROUP BY I.film_id),

film_categories AS 
(
SELECT FC.film_id, STRING_AGG(C.name, ',') AS categories 
FROM Film_Category AS FC  
INNER JOIN Category AS C ON C.category_id = FC.category_id
GROUP BY FC.film_id
)

SELECT F.title, ISNULL(rental_count, 0 ) AS rental_count, FC.categories AS [name]    
FROM  Film AS F 
LEFT  JOIN  film_rents AS FR ON F.film_id = FR.film_id
INNER JOIN film_categories AS FC ON FC.film_id =  F.film_id
```

Comment: Exactly! So each film has one or more category and I wish to get the counts of those! @Afshin Amiri

Comment: Which SQL Server version you use?

Comment: Amazing thing is that the only correct answer did not get upvote :)